# How to retrieve data by using select2 jquery (multiple select)

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu

how to retrieve data by using multi-select drop-down, it always cannot display the data

---

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Marketing Campaign</label>
    <select class="js-example-basic-multiple form-control" id="mc" name="mc" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Please Select One" value="<?php echo $mc?>" readonly>
    <?php
        echo '<option></option>';
        $query5 = mysqli_query($connect,"select name from mktcp order by name asc")or die(mysqli_error());
        while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query5))
        {   
            if($mc == $rows['name'])
            {
                echo '<option value="'.$rows['name'].'" selected="selected">'.$rows['name'].'</option>';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<option value="'.$rows['name'].'">'.$rows['name'].'</option>';
            }
        }
    ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what's the problem you're having or what you want to achieve. Add the current output, the desired output, describe your question better.

Comment: Improve code format

Answer (score 0):

If you add [] to the name:

```
<select id="mc" name="mc[]" multiple="multiple">
```

Then the selects will show up as a array in you post variables.

See the example below:

```
<?php
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($_POST);
  echo "</pre>"
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
    <select id="mc" name="mc[]"  multiple="multiple">
      <option>Test1</option>
      <option>Test2</option>
      <option>Test3</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

The result will be:

```
Array
(
    [mc] => Array
        (
            [0] => Test2
            [1] => Test3
        )
)
```

I think you need to remove the "readonly" option